# Any solutions to the functional equation $f(x) = f(x-1)-f(x+1)-ix^3f(x)$?

Tags: functions, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

Are there any solutions to this functional equation:

$$f(x) = f(x-1)-f(x+1)-ix^3f(x)$$

I am not familiar with functional equations and have no idea where to start. All I can say is that $f(0) = f(-1)-f(1)$.

[Wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f(x)%20%3D%20f(x-1)-f(x%2B1)-ix%5E3f(x)) gives a recurrence relation for $f(n), n\in \mathbb{N}$ provided we know $f(0),f(1)$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: One solution to $f(0)=f(-1)-f(1)$ is $f(x)=|x|$. But that doesn't solve the functional equation. Two others are $f(x)=x^2$, $f(x)=sin(\pi x)$ but again don't solve equation.

Comment: What is the domain/codomain of $f$?

Comment: Also even if you know $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ this functional equations  will only define integer values. You'd have to define $f(x)$ for all $x \in [0,2]$ for example uniquely define $f$.

Comment: @flawr the domain and codomain are the reals

Comment: @Dman Can you please define $i$ then? Usually $i$ denotes the imaginary unit.

Comment: @flawr whoops, sorry, the codomain is $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Start by collecting like terms, i.e. put both of the $f(x)$ terms together.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Take [inverse Mellin transform](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/mellin.pdf):

$\mathcal{M}^{-1}_{x\to s}\left\{f(x)\right\}=\mathcal{M}^{-1}_{x\to s}\left\{f(x-1)\right\}-\mathcal{M}^{-1}_{x\to s}\left\{f(x+1)\right\}-\mathcal{M}^{-1}_{x\to s}\left\{ix^3f(x)\right\}$

$F(s)=\left(\dfrac{1}{s}-s\right)F(s)+i\left(s\dfrac{d}{ds}\right)^3F(s)$

Which converts to an third-order ODE

Comment: Inverse Mellin transform assumes some analyticity in $x$ of $f$, or $L^2$ integrability. But in these cases, this is a nice idea!